# How much are the 500, 600, 700 usw. steps in Figma for colors

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css, figma

I want to make SASS Mixins for my color scheme in the tailwind style.

For every color I want to generate a 400, 300, 200 and 100 and so on version.

Now it would be nice to know in what percentage tailwind steps this.

I found nothing in the internet to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually use https://javisperez.github.io/tailwindcolorshades/#/ to generate shades it will output something like:

```
  concrete: {
    100: '#FEFEFE',
    200: '#FCFCFC',
    300: '#FAFAFA',
    400: '#F6F6F6',
    500: '#F2F2F2',
    600: '#DADADA',
    700: '#919191',
    800: '#6D6D6D',
    900: '#494949',
  },
```

That you can include in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind's default colors are all handpicked, they do not have a tool to generate color palettes, so you would have to do the same.

From the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#generating-custom-color-palettes):

**Generating custom color palettes**

> A common question we get is "how do I generate the 100–900 shades of
>   my own custom colors?".
>
> Bad news: color is complicated and we've yet to find a tool that does
>   a good job generating these sorts of color palettes. We picked all of
>   Tailwind's default colors by hand, balancing them by eye. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I found this figma plugin: https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/815578663120885543/Tailwind-Color-Generator

That generates the custom color palette for you to use in your designs and then you can export it into your SCSS Files - the result should be the same.